# How do I disable user account switching in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, indicator, session, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to permanently disable user switching in Gnome 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153930/how-to-permanently-disable-user-switching-in-gnome-3)

Is there any way to disable the "switch user account" menu on the top bar? I'm using Gnome 3 on Precise Pangolin. Thanks in advance