# How to remove the switch user account option in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-2d

We are looking for a way to permanently remove the Switch User Account function from our install of Ubuntu Unity. Note, this function appears when you right or left click on the user name in the upper right-hand corner. It then displays a list of 5-10 users that have logged in along with the option to Switch User Account. We know that we can do this by defaulting to gnome, but we would like the option of using Unity as well, but without the Switch User Account option.

We have already tried dconf-editor, gsettings and several other options to remove the users name list, Switch User Account option from appearing in the drop-down list. We know this can be done for one user at a time, but we are wanting to do this for all users on roughly 160 workstations.

Some options that we have already tried are:

- [How to permanently disable user switching in Gnome 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153930/how-to-permanently-disable-user-switching-in-gnome-3)
- http://ubuntu.5.x6.nabble.com/Remove-switch-user-from-unity-top-left-menu-on-precise-td4933613.html

This is a visual of what we are trying to remove:

[image: !]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what your looking for based on your question, but Ubuntu Tweak has a option that will let you remove the user indicator that you circled in red.

Comment: This is a somewhat messy/incomplete workaround. If you enter the guest account directly from the active account, then exit the guest account, you are able to login to a different user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried editing the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.indicator.session.gschema.xml` file simply changing this:

```
<key type="b" name="user-show-menu">
  <default>true</default>
  <summary>Determine the visibility of the User Menu</summary>
  <description>Allow for the user menu to be hidden by the user.</description>
</key> </code>
```

to this (**true** to **false**):

```
<key type="b" name="user-show-menu">
  <default>false</default>
  <summary>Determine the visibility of the User Menu</summary>
  <description>Allow for the user menu to be hidden by the user.</description>
</key>
```

Then **make a backup** of `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled`
Then run

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

Normally this would set it as default for all users.

**UPDATE:**

[Florian Diesch](https://askubuntu.com/users/2369/florian-diesch) pointed out in the comments that it is better to write an override file, because the .xml could be overwritten in an update, thus or settings will be lost. So instead of directly modifying the gschema.xml make a `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/myoverride.gschema.override` file with the following contents:

```
[com.canonical.indicator.session]
user-show-menu=false
```

The rest is the same: backup and compile.

Comment: Better use an [override file](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/gsettings-override-2011-07-04-15-45) instead of editing the .xml file as a package update may overwrite the .xml file.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Thx for that info.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick for all users that are logging in for us. Thank you!

Comment: Note, we did the override file option.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different in 14.04 Unity (3D):

```
[apps/indicator-session]
user-show-menu=false
```

And sysadmins probably want to set it in /etc/dconf, maybe even lock it.
See dconf System Administrator Guide for more.

Answer (score 0):

Colleague of mine just figured out a workaround for this in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, by appending the following to /etc/bash.bashrc

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu false`

This way when any user login occurs the switch user menu does not appear.