# Removal of the Lock/Switch Account menu in gnome desktop Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: unity, gnome, menu, switch-user

We are looking for a way to remove the list of previously logged on users from the shutdown menu in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running Gnome Classic Desktop. We have lots of computers in a lab environment where we do not want other users to know login names of previous users that have used that particular machine.

Any help on removing this list would be appreciated.

Note, this is after a user logs into Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and when you click on the little gear icon in the upper right-hand corner to shutdown|Logout|Suspend|Restart it also displays Lock/Switch Account along with a list of user names.

Thank you!

Comment: You do understand there must be hundreds of ways to list users on your system, anything from `ls /home` to `cat /etc/passwd` to commands such as who and last to looking at the logs .

Comment: Yes, we do understand that you can use other measures such as getent passwd and the like. However, we would still like to clean up our menu options to only display the currently logged in user.

Comment: This answer solved our problem. [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/390465/how-to-remove-the-switch-user-account-option-in-unity-2d/390483#390483)

Answer (score 0):

The correct GSettings key for this is org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching, however an inspection of the indicator-session code shows this is not being correctly applied. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1325353