# Can't switch between users without logging out

Tags: lightdm, gdm, session

I have two users and can't switch from one to the other, regardless of whether I'm using gdm or lightdm.

The only thing that works is logging out and logging back in with the other user; I think I can start only one session.

What could be the problem?

Comment: gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 
......   :   false

Comment: I've no problem in user switching, the problem is that all user need to use the same session ctrl+alt+F6; and f7 cant be used

Comment: If you can add any further details to your question, that might help people find the answer

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with the nvidia-340 driver. I switched back to nouveau and now all is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153930/how-to-permanently-disable-user-switching-in-gnome-3) about **disabling** user switching. The answers describe several settings to disable the feature but you can use the information to check and re-enable user switching.