# Keyboard and mouse/touchpad lock up waking up from suspend mode

Tags: keyboard, suspend, mouse, touchpad

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. As my laptop is quite dated and as I don't have an SSD, it takes a long time to boot into OS so I always leave the computer in suspend mode. Problem is about 1 of 5 times I switch on the PC from suspend mode, keyboard and mouse functions are gone after I hit the first key on my keyboard to enter my login password. As soon as I hit the first key, login password box is full of dots (like keyboard is stuck and fills the box with letters). In this case I need to go back to suspend mode (via touchscreen) and switch it on again.

Looking forward to hear your advice on this weird problem.

Comment: Do you want to post your solution as an answer? Give some details of how you disabled repeat keys - it could help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by disabling repeat keys function via settings > universal access > typing tab.

Edit: Sorry, I thought that I had solved the problem but it persists. It happened again just now. I wasn't able to login when I resumed the pc from suspend mode. Keyboard and touchpad wasn't working. I had to suspend the pc again via touchscreen and everything working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the `switch user` function. [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153930/how-to-permanently-disable-user-switching-in-gnome-3)

That usualy solves problems like that.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of rogue letters being typed when trying to login?!

Comment: @ Will I don't know, but for me it worked.