# Remember running program before shutting down

Tags: gnome, 21.10, session

My computer doesn't support hibernate so if i restart i want to have all my running applications and browser(tabs) the same as when it was before i turned of my **Ubuntu 21.10**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically Remember current Running Applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084389/automatically-remember-current-running-applications)

Comment: Vanadium's link is probably going to fulfill this need, in the meantime firefox pretty much already does this with the check of a box in the settings.... I don't even have the box checked, the "recently closed windows" under the history menu option always brings them back. Virtualization solutions, like Virtualbox", will give you the ability to "hibernate" the VM with the "Save State" option, allowing you to power off the host machine and bring the saved state of the VM back up at a later time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to permanently disable user switching in Gnome 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153930/how-to-permanently-disable-user-switching-in-gnome-3)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not easily possible on Ubuntu with your constraints.

Comment: The comment goes to something that is stated to be 18.04 specific and for which the only answer has a dead link. I vote to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link as it may be suitable for your OS. It shows how you can enable "auto-save-session".

[https://vitux.com/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-debian/#:~:text=From%20the%20Dconf%20editor%20window,next%20time%20you%20log%20in](https://vitux.com/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-debian/#:%7E:text=From%20the%20Dconf%20editor%20window,next%20time%20you%20log%20in).

Comment: i do not think this is a standard option in system settings,can you please add some information about how to enable this?